# Dotted 8th note in a triplet swing rhythm

Tags: theory

I'm looking at isn't she lovely by Stevie Wonder and as I've only been reading music for about a year I've not really come across this type of notation - I'm fine with the first two beats as they're just crotchets, but on the 3rd beat, the notation shows an 8th note rest, followed by the notes B, E, G* (an E chord), followed by another 8th note rest, which make up the whole triplet - but the B note is a dotted 8th note which in a typical straight 4/4 rhythm would mean the dotted 8th note is played as 3/4 of a beat (an 8th note + a 16th note). So how would this dotted eigth note be played in an 8th note triplet? Or swung 4/4 rhythm? It won't let me upload a pic as it's too big but I that makes sense, Cheers!

Comment: Upload the picture here: https://imgur.com/upload or something similar and I'll fix it for you. Just give me the link when you're done.

Comment: I have a feeling this question was downvoted because the OP didn't provide a picture, but please keep in mind that new users can't add pictures to their posts (as the OP noted). The question itself seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost a shuffle, sort of swing time.

Imagine it written not in 4/4, but in 12/8. So you count **1**23 **2**23 **3**23 **4**23.
That problematic bit is on beat 3, except the E chord comes in *after* **3**, just on the '23' after it

To explain another way - imagine counting 1 - 12 in that bar. 123 and 456 are the first two chords, miss 7, play 89 using that E chord, and E again on 10 11 12.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Study the classic Morecambe and Wise song 'Boom Oo Yata-Ta-Ta'.    That's the rhythm, split between treble and bass. (Ignoring two extra 8ths in the bass.)